# how to update data that appear in listbox control

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox-control

I retrieve data into a `ListBox`, when I click a search button.

How to update the `ListBox` when I search for another word?

How do I remove items from my `ListBox` and get the new data?

This is my code in the `Button` `Click` event handler:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (user_data.Text != null)
    {
        user_info = user_data.Text.Trim();
        words = user_info.Split(' ');

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            letters = word.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
            {
                string s = letters[i] + ".jpg";
                souce_data.Add(s);
            }
            phoronic_name.DataContext = souce_data;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CollectionViewSourceIsCrazyUsefulForBindingToFilteredObservableCollectionsOnWindowsPhone8.aspx

I am on mobile thats why cant explain in detail.

Comment: so there is no any way to remove items from listbox